# PHP Resize with proportions

Tags: php, upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating image size ratio for resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594089/calculating-image-size-ratio-for-resizing)

So I have a simple upload script that resizes the uploaded picture, I would like to force the width size, and let the height get automatically proportioned.

Here is my upload script:

```
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
        $dirupload = "../images/";
        $dirupload = $dirupload . basename( $_FILES['image-upload']['name']);
        $useless = $_POST['useless'];
        $imageupload = ($_FILES['image-upload']['name']);
        $uploadedfileupload = $_FILES['image-upload']['tmp_name'];
        $uploadedfiletypeupload = $_FILES['image-upload']['type']; 

        $query_add="SELECT * FROM produits ORDER BY position";
        $result_add=mysql_query($query_add);
        $num_add=mysql_num_rows($result_add);
        $add_add=$num_add+1;

        if (!($uploadedfiletypeupload =="image/pjpeg" OR $uploadedfiletypeupload =="image/jpeg" OR $uploadedfiletypeupload =="image/jpg")){
            echo "L'image doit être en .jpg ou .jpeg";
        }else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image-upload']['tmp_name'], $dirupload)){     
            $sql="INSERT INTO produits (position) VALUES ('$add_add')";
            if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)){
                die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            }       


            $newnameupload = "../images/produit" . mysql_insert_id() . ".jpg";
            rename ("../images/$imageupload","$newnameupload");    
            $orig_imageupload = imagecreatefromjpeg("../image/$newnameupload");
            $sm_imageupload = imagecreatetruecolor(274,219);
            imagecopyresampled($sm_imageupload,$orig_imageupload,0,0,0,0,274,219,imagesx($orig_imageupload),imagesy($orig_imageupload));
            imagejpeg($sm_imageupload, $newnameupload, 100);

        }else{
            echo "Un probleme est survenue";
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on trying to get this to work ? (yes I do have the height set for now in the script)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What's wrong with your script?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the script, I would just like too see how only set the width and let the height get automatically proportioned.

Comment: There are many image control libraries for PHP, you can look for one and use it. It will resize with proportions or crop to fill blank spaces and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the width to height factor like

`$factor = $height /$width;`

then

```
$newHeight = $newWidth * $factor;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, the best way is to use some image processing library. Because it is kinda *crop-and-resize* option. Sometimes image can't be proportionally reduced to the required size without cropping.

Take a look at:

- **[phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/)**
- **[WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/)**

Both of them have built-in functionality that you need and are rather friendly and flexible.