# How can I crop the image in php with given coordinates of X,Y,Width and Height

Tags: php, image, crop

I am trying to crop the original image with given X, Y, Width and Height coordinates. 
But it does not crop the image properly.

Here is my code

```
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    $source_x = $_POST['x'];
    $source_y = $_POST['y'];
    $width = $_POST['w'];
    $height = $_POST['h'];

    $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg('path of the orignal Image');

    imagecopy($dest, $src, 30, 30, $source_x, $source_y, $width, $height);

    $cropped_image = "Path where to store the cropped image";

    imagejpeg($dest, $cropped_image, 100);
```

Using above code, I am able to crop the image, But it doesn't crop in given coordinate.

Any help will be useful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594089/calculating-image-size-ratio-for-resizing

Comment: @Kiren Siva  I don't want to resize the image. I want to crop the part of image and save only that cropped image.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the **imagecrop** PHP function.
Here is the link to the manual: [imagecrop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecrop.php)

So, in your case it would look like this:

```
$to_crop_array = array('x' =>$source_x , 'y' => $source_y, 'width' => $width, 'height'=> $height);
$dest = imagecrop($src, $to_crop_array);
```