# Cakephp upload image ratio

Tags: php, image, validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Is there any specific way how we can restrict **upload image ratio** to 16:9 in cakephp 2.3?

Comment: Not really but PHP provides functions to handle that. With getimagesize(), you will be able to manually calculate this ratio. http://php.net/manual/fr/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: I know this is not about the question, but if you're new to CakePHP and you want to implement a image upload module, I have a tip for you: Keep the upload code in the model. Use model's callbacks (beforeSave(), afterSave()) to manage your upload. Remember that: Fat model, tiny controller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you did *any* research on this yourself... So here is just the basic concept:

- **Don't** use a component, use a model or behavior instead
- [Create a custom validation rule](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-validation-rules)
- [Get the image size](https://www.google.de/search?q=phph%20get%20image%20size&oq=phph%20get%20image%20size) inside the rule, [calculate the ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594089/calculating-image-size-ratio-for-resizing) and (in)validate the file field if it doesn't match your ratio.